# Odoo hide edit and more buttons if not admin

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to hide the edit and more button in user form if the connected user is not the admin.
Here is my code

```
 <xpath expr='//form[@string="Users"]' position='attributes'>
            <attribute name="edit" >{'false':[('id', '!=', '1')]}</attribute>
                <attribute name="more">{'false':[('id', '!=', '1')]}</attribute>
            </xpath>
```

i get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

Comment: If you really want such hard access rule, you can change odoo's client and just hide those two "buttons" by using j-query. But i don't know why someone has such requirements to an erp software. There is no sense in "admin is the only one to edit records".

Comment: In odoo you can create a user (manager) with administration:Acces Rights. Then that user can edit the admin information such as password , administration ... That is why i want to hide those button for users other than administrator.

Comment: Sorry i just misread your first part. That clearly makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you trying achive is not possible using expression, rather I would advise to user "Customized Views"

1. Make out of user form edit="false" this will make edit button go away for all users (res.users.form).
2. Now go to `Customized Views` under `Settings/Technical/User Interface/Customized Views`, you need to be in `debug` mode to be able to see this menu.
3. Under `Customized Views` create a new record and choose User : `Admin` and in original view choose : `res.users.form` and in `View Architecture`
    copy and pare original view View Architecture and just remove edit='false'

This should help, I believe.

Bests

Comment: Hi @shodowsjedi , i don't have edit='false' in the original view. Even when i add it , just for testing purpose. the button is always there.

Comment: @OumarDiarra: it will show button if your security rules, is allowing other user to edit the record.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding @shodowsjedi's answer, To achieve what you want you have to create two views (They're essentially the same just that one is attached to a specific group and will be displayed for a user that belongs to that group)

This is a mockup of how your `xml` file should look

```
<!--original form view-->
<record id="model_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">your.model</field>
<field name="model">your.model</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<form string="Users">
    <!--whatever is in your form -->
</field>
</record>

<!--inherited formview to hide edit option -->
<record id="model_form_view_noedit" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">your.model</field>
<field name="model">your.model</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="model_form_view"/>
<field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.group_user') ])]"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr='//form[@string="Users"]' position='attributes'>
        <attribute name="edit">false</attribute>
    </xpath>
</field>
</record>
```

It's always better to know how things work from the backend in Odoo